# docker run -p only containerPort, what is it

Tags: docker, networking

In [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports), there is a format like `docker run -p 80 ...`. what does it when I only specify a single value like that?

Well, actually, I can do it myself in my terminal, but I'm little bit unpleasant that there are no document about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give port with single value, It will be the port of your container, and since the host port is not given, It will bind to dynamically published port of the host. This means your docker container will be assigned a port dynamically by the host itself.
For example when I run this

```
docker run --name python-app -d -p 5000 my-python-app
```

It will assign container 5000 port to random dynamic port of host. When I run this:

```
docker port python-app
```

I get random host port.

[image]

That means I will be able to access my app using 32769 port.

For more information on this read this [link](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/)